# Limit field length value in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch cluster that contains lots of data with individual fields and their values. I have a field name **Description** and it has a small paragraph as a value. The value length is different in different fields. I want to limit the value on those fields. I have tried the following methods.

- I created an index with custom mapping

```
        "description" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 150
            }
          }
        }
```

- The index data field values mappings are showing me that they are in 150 but my description values are the same as before.
- I also tried to modify the data using the

```
PUT index_name/_settings
{
  "index.mapping.field_name_length.limit": 150
}
```

But none of this worked. My description data is still the same as before. So what should I do? Should I try to limit my description value while I upload them on my cluster or can I limit the values from the elastic search cluster after I upload them?

My main task is to set the description data to a maximum length of 150 characters. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The configuration you've added will not modify the `_source` document you're sending, only what gets indexed.

You have two options to shorten the value of a given field:

A. Modify the source document before sending it to Elasticsearch

B. Have your documents flow through an [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) that will do this for you:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/shorten-description
{
  "description": "Shorten my description field",
  "processors": [
    {
      "script": {
        "if": "ctx.description != null",
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "ctx.description = ctx.description.substring(0, params.length)",
        "params": {
          "length": 150
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And then you can index your document using that ingest pipeline:

```
PUT my-index/_doc/1?pipeline=shorten-description
{
  "description": "...."
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. As per the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-above.html): "Strings longer than the ignore_above setting will not be indexed or stored" so it should not be store.

Just tried on my ELK installation and if I set ignore_above: 20 for instance, the field stopped coming since it was mostly above 20 chars.

Comment: @Zubeyir if the string is longer nothing gets indexed at all. What this solution provides is to at least index as many characters as permitted

Comment: Now I got it: if the field is longer than the ignore_above limit, it is **not** indexed and therefore it is **not** visible in the Discover but it **is** available in the _source (unless disabled).

The definition in the documentation is somehow confusing. It could be understood like "nothing is stored" but actually it means "it is not stored as indexed".

So this solution (indexing as many characters permitted) is a great approach! Thanks.